# How to compare two revisions in Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

My team is using Bitbucket for our git repository and we've recently starting using the pull request functionality for code reviews.  It works fine on the first review, but if it goes through multiple iterations (that is, changes are made and pull request updated), I would like to see a link with just the new changes that were made since the last code review.

I looked into the "compare" functionality but the UI looks like it can only compare between branches.  Is there a simple way to get a diff between two commits?

Comment: Intro into [working with pull requests](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html) or  [commit-level review](https://blogs.atlassian.com/2016/07/new-features-bitbucket-4-8/) a new feature in bitbuckt 4.8

Answer (score 108):

This is just a slight modification to the answers already given but adding #diff to the end instead of #commits is usually what I'm looking for. Also as others may have mentioned the best results for me are usually obtained by placing the newer commit first and the older one second but that will depend on your particular needs.

```
https://bitbucket.org/<OWNER>/<REPO>/branches/compare/<commit-hash>..<commit-hash-older>#diff
```

Comment: I wish they would add some intuitive gui to track commit revision (similar to gerrit)

Comment: I tried this answer today without success. Can anyone verify that it's still valid with the current version of Bitbucket?

Comment: I just tried this with two commits from the tortoisehg project and it still appears to work. Here is an example link: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/branches/compare/5b660cc..3e1da5d#diff

Comment: Worked great. Inserted the `owner/repo`, copied the hashes from the commit-list, hit enter, and bam. Nice and easy diff view.  (Why this isn't an obvious thing in their GUI however...)

Comment: @NightOwl - Are you using Stash/bitbucket server?  If so, this only works on bitbucket.org - https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-2550

Answer (score 37):

The search fields in the branch/tag dropdowns on the Compare page on bitbucket.org now supports pasted-in commit hashes.

So now you can just go to `https://bitbucket.org/<owner>/<repo>/branches/compare/` and paste the hashes into the dropdowns instead of URL hacking!

[image: drop down, then paste in commit hash]

Comment: This worked for me but I needed to edit the url to end in #diff instead of #commits, as per earlier answer, otherwise it showed no changes.

Comment: @brian.keng can you mark this as correct answer please?

Answer (score 26):

Try something like:

`https://bitbucket.org/<OWNER>/<PROJECT>/branches/compare/<commit1>..<commit2>#commits`

Taken from: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4779/ability-to-diff-between-any-two-commits

Comment: Does not work in version 4.14. Gives a Dead Link error when you add anything after ``compare/`` including the above.

Comment: Same with the other syntax mentioned in https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11657/allow-commit-ids-to-be-used-in-compare which gives just a generic 404 and the path under it.

Answer (score 26):

Bitbucket supports comparing tags now.

```
https://bitbucket.org/<OWNER>/<PROJECT>/branches/compare/<tag1>%0D<tag2>
```

Comment: This gives me a page but does not do a diff between TAGS, which is what I was looking for

Comment: For posterity, it works, but `tag1` must start with "v" and be newer, `tag2` is older. For example, https://bitbucket.org/codsen/array-includes-with-glob/branches/compare/v2.3.6%0Dv2.3.5 — other way around won't work and without "v" it won't work — both cases will lead to 404.

Comment: That did the trick. `https://bitbucket.org/<OWNER>/<PROJECT>/branches/compare/<TAG1>%0D<TAG2>?w=1#diff` This shows the diff and ignores whitespace differences.

Answer (score 11):

I have Bitbucket Server, version:v4.4.1

The answer with me was this.

```
http://<path-to-my-server>/projects/<project-name>/repos/<repo-name>/commits/<old>?to=<new>
```

I was looking for this answer because in my project we use git submodules, and in pull requests I can only see the old commit sha vs the new commit sha of each submodule that changed. There is no link to click or anything (that I know of) to jump to this diff view. This url allows me to view what changed in submodules too.

Btw, if someone knows of a better way of comparing two commits in submodules during a pull request, please let me know.

Comment: All this does for me, on Bitbucket Server v4.9.0, is show the first commit. It does not compare the revisions.

Comment: @Jeff did you try switching <old> to <new> I might have mixed them up, if so, then I will correct my answer

Comment: Yes, same issue. In fact, as of November 2016 (this month), Atlassian is saying that this feature isn't supported yet in Bitbucket Server: https://jira.atlassian.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/BSERV-2550. Are you sure it is doing what you think it is on your system?

Comment: I found this to work for a sudo for tags, by taking the commit hash for each tag

Answer (score 6):

The Bitbucket compare view format is following:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<owner>/<repo>/branches/compare/<new>%0D<old>
```

Given an example `ged/ruby-pg` (RubyGem, a ruby library):

**To compare two releases (from v0.18.1 to v0.18.2)**

https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/branches/compare/v0.18.2%0Dv0.18.1

**To compare two revisions (from f97dd6c to 22a3612)**

https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/branches/compare/22a361201fd1d387d59a066b179124694a446f38%0Df97dd6cb4f34da6a62c4339887249115c7c25b9c

Answer (score 5):

GO to your bitbucket repository > Branches
[image]

Click on the menu icon and on compare

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this inside of a pull request, say after someone makes a push to a branch to fix review findings. To my knowledge there's no UI for this yet, but you can enter the url like this:

`https://<bitbucket-server>/projects/<PROJECT>/repos/<REPO>/pull-requests/<PR-NUM>/<commit-hash>?since=<commit-hash-older>`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was 
    https://bitbucket.org/-theusername-/-projectnamealllowercase-/branches/compare/-Leftalphanumberic_commitcode-..-Rightalphanumeric_commit-#commits

Replace the `-username-` with your `username`

Thanks to @Aguardientico

Answer (score 0):

Create a light tag to the commit(s) you want to compare.
git -a [tagname] [commit_sha]

Then in Bitbucket, in the compare menu (the one to do pull requests) simply compare with tags.

Answer (score 0):

At the command prompt

`git log -p -1`

> This shows the comparison with the previous version.

`git log -p -5`

> This shows the last 5 revisions, comparing two successive versions (n & n-1, n-1 & n-2, etc).

I realize, this is not ideal to show direct difference between two specific versions.

Ref. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Answer (score -4):

Via terminal, run git on your project path:

`git diff <new commit> <old commit>`

Ex: `git diff 26cf60f be5f978`

Comment: This is how to compare things with git, on the command line; the question was how to do it in Bitbucket, on the website :)

Comment: bitbucket does not have these features.. hence cmd line is the only way..

Comment: This was the answer I found most useful. Agreed the question states bitbucket and this answer does provide a solution that works nicely with bitbucket was well as other git solutions.